# Showing image when available

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am trying to create a web interface for a scientific code. The user will provide some inputs and submit through a HTML form. A php script will take the input and run code on server. In the end of it, one or more (not more than 10) images will be created. The code may take few seconds to hours, depending upon the inputs.

How can I show these images on the webpage after completion, and make them available for download?

Comment: Do you know images urls before they are created ?

Comment: Generate ticket, when the job is completed send a link at pictures to email.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to have a method that creates a unique identifier upon completion.

So this can be as simple as checking to see if the image exists, and if not notify the user that it is still in progress.

so something like:

```
if (file_exists($image_file)) { do something... } 
else { echo 'Files still in progress....'; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your going todo the *scientific code* in a background process, the issue would be the frontend.

To make it simple, I would assign the job/calculation a **unique url**, that relates to the results, much like [codepad](http://codepad.org/), [viper7](http://codepad.viper-7.com/), [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) do, then while there on the page [poll (AJAX) the server](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D%20polling%20server%20ajax) for the images/results. Dont even attempt todo any submitted code, while the user waits or on the request thread.